# Get the installed plugins metadata using Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, metadata

I'm making a QGIS plugin and I need get the metadata of the installed plugins. Currently it works only if the plugin manager was opened manually before. If QGIS is reopened and the plugin manager was not opened by the user, the line "self.iface.pluginManagerInterface().pluginMetadata(plugin)" always returns "None".

I tried using "iface.pluginManagerInterface().pluginMetadata('db_manager')" directly in the python console inside QGIS and it has the same problem.

Part of my code looks like this:

```
    for plugin in plugins:
        metadata = self.iface.pluginManagerInterface().pluginMetadata(plugin)
        if metadata is None:
            continue
        if self.dlg.chk_official_plugins.isChecked():
            if metadata['zip_repository'] == 'QGIS Official Plugin Repository':
                self.plugins_metadata.append(metadata)  # Adds the plugin metadata to the list
            else:
                continue
        else:
            self.plugins_metadata.append(metadata)
```

I've tried opening the plugin manager using "iface.pluginManagerInterface().showPluginManager(0)", but it didn't fix the problem like manually opening the plugin manager.

I also tried to update the repositories, but that didn't work either. I used "pyplugin_installer.instance().fetchAvailablePlugins(False)"

Is there a class I need to initialize before being able to get the metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the problem. It was a problem with the metadata cache. I was able to refresh the cache using [`pyplugin_installer`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/pyplugin_installer/installer.py).

```
import pyplugin_installer

pyplugin_installer.instance().reloadAndExportData()
```

Then I could get the metadata of all the installed plugins using the code I already had.